# Exchange 2013 - Edit Mailbox in ECP, Page Blank

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2013

We have Exchange 2013 on Server 2012, and when logged into the ECP if I double click on a user mailbox the EditMailbox.aspx page pops up, but all the fields are blank and the links on the left hand side don't work - see attached image.

This previously worked and the only things which I know to have changed are Windows Updates applied last week.  We did install a new public certificate, but that was a few months back and I am 90% sure it has worked since then.

I've have checked the back end certificate in IIS as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2971270/blank-page-after-login-exchange-eac-owa-ecp (even though it's not exactly the same error!).

I've checked the Application Event log and can't see anything in there.

The popup pages for groups, resources etc all work perfectly.

Any idea where I could look next?  Which log files might shed some light?

[MailboxPopupPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP3Az.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do All mailboxes in EAC have this issue? If run "get-mailbox" in EMS, do all properties show correctly?
How many Exchange servers do you have? If many servers, you can test in different servers and check if there is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of Error:** SSL Certificate Binding  Issue

**Steps to Resolve Issue:**

1. Open IIS manager.
2. Go to the sites under Exchange Server Environment and Select “Exchange Back End”.
3. Open Bindings from right side “Actions” panel.
4. Select https under binding settings and click on Edit.
5. Select “MS Exchange” under SSL certificate and click on OK to apply settings.
6. Now, you should try to open Exchange EAC or OWA.